# python append error index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I used sklearn LogisticRegression and want to see the param C because my model seems overfitting.So I do this:

```
weightes,params = [],[]

for c in np.arange(-5,5):
    lr = LogisticRegression(C=10**c,random_state=0,n_jobs=-1)
    lr.fit(trainDataX,trainDataY)
    weightes.append(lr.coef_[1])
    params.append(10**c)
```

But I got:

```
IndexError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-2b13dbdd7faf> in <module>()
      4     lr = LogisticRegression(C=10**c,random_state=0,n_jobs=-1)
      5     lr.fit(trainDataX,trainDataY)
----> 6     weightes.append(lr.coef_[1])
      7     params.append(10**c)

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I really want to know why and how to solve this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array stored in `lr.coef_` has only one element in it. The logistic regression model stores the fit intercept in `lr.intercept` and the coefficients of the predictor variables in `lr.coef`. You must have a model with a single predictor variable.